# Programa que crie dois vetores com 10 elementos aleatórios entre 1 e 100

Tags: python

Faça um programa que crie dois vetores com 10 elementos aleatórios entre 1 e 100. Gere um terceiro vetor de 20 elementos, cujos valores deverão ser compostos pelos elementos intercalados dos dois outros vetores. Imprima os três vetores.

gostaria de saber se o código que fiz está correto e se possível me mostrar uma outra maneira de faze-lo obrigado.

```
import random
lista1 = []
lista2 = []
lista3 = []

while len(lista1) < 10:
    numero = random.randint(1,100)
    if numero not in lista1:
        lista1.append(numero)
        lista3.append(numero)


while len(lista2)  < 10:
    numero = random.randint(1,100)
    if numero not in lista2:
        lista2.append(numero)
        lista3.append(numero)

lista1.sort()        
lista2.sort()
lista3.sort()

print(lista1)
print(lista2)
print(lista3)
```

Comment: O seu programa está fazendo alguma coisa que você não esperava?

Comment: Na verdade não sei se é a melhor maneira de fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você usar o método sort não conseguiremos saber se os elementos estão intercalados. Um exemplo: 
`lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` e 
`lista2 = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`. 
Neste caso a `lista3` seria 
`[1, 11, 2, 12, 3, 13, 4, 14, 5, 15, 6, 16, 7, 17, 8, 18, 9, 19, 10, 20]`.

Sugiro dividir a lógica em duas partes: primeiro montar as listas, sem sortear e sem a preocupação de ter elementos distintos. Depois usar os índices possíveis, com `range(10)` para ir incluindo os elementos na `lista3` num loop. Em primeiro lugar `lista3.append(lista1[0])` `lista3.append(lista2[0])` e assim por diante.